# Difference in pixel size between gdalinfo and gdal2tiles

Tags: gdal, pixel, gdal2tiles, gdalinfo

I'm getting two different pixel size values, does anyone know what is the reason for this issue?

From gdalinfo:

[image: From gdalinfo]

From gdal2tiles.py:

[image: From gdal2tiles]

GDAL version: 3.20

Comment: Two stabs in the dark. Is the initial raster in a different CRS than 3857, leading to a scale/resolution difference after reprojection on the fly during tiling?
Alternately, is there any rotation involved? The parameters of the geotransform are the exact x and y resolutions only if there is no rotation - see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281132/why-doesnt-gdalinfo-report-pixel-size

Comment: What do you do for for getting the pixel size from gdal2tiles?

Comment: @Houska It's the same file which was projected to UTM. No rotation.

Comment: @user30184 i just edited the code in order to log it.

Comment: What did you edit here https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal2tiles.py and what is your exact gdal2tiles command? Have you considered if it is possible to keep the same extent and pixel size when the image must be split into some amount of full 256x256 sized tiles?

Comment: @user30184 i just added "print(self.out_gt)" at line 1754. The command is "gdal2tiles.py -d -v --tilesize=256 file.tif"

Comment: @user30184 I'm really sorry but I'm not really sure what do you mean about keeping the same extent and pixel size. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You can forget. I guessed that you were using the raster profile. If your out_gt is set with this `# Read the georeference
        self.out_gt = self.warped_input_dataset.GetGeoTransform()` then you deal with data that is warped. You wrote that your source data is in some UTM zone, did I understand right?